# Get listitem with shortest length from a python list

Tags: python-2.7

I have a orginal list with three words: 'hello', 'hi' and 'Good day'. 
I want to create a new_list containing the item with the shortest length. How do I write that code? I use Python 2.7.

```
original_list=['hello','hi','Good day']

 Word      Length
'Hello'      5
'Hi'         2
'Good day'   8
```

Expected output (since I only want the item with the shortest length):

```
new_list=['Hi']
```

Comment: What if you have multiple items with the same shortest length in the list: `['hello','hi','Good day', 'me']` - what should the output be?

Comment: Closed as a duplicate - the duplicate thread has multiple different solutions to the problem. If a single shortest item is good enough then you can go with the posted answer. Thanks.

Comment: Fair point. In my scenario there can never be two words with the same length. Your answer solved the problem. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`min()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#min) takes a `key` function as an argument, use `len` as a `key` function:

```
>>> original_list = ['hello','hi','Good day']
>>> new_list = [min(original_list, key=len)]
>>> new_list
['hi']
```

This though does not handle multiple items with the same shortest length - e.g. `['hello','hi','Good day', 'me']` input list.